# Comment formuleriez-vous à l’oral l’idée exprimée dans les phrases citées dans le corps de la question?

Tags: choix-de-mot, formulation, reformulation

> Ton conjoint et toi vous êtes mis d’accord sur le choix des décorations de Noël que tu as a achetées cette année ?

> C’est avec l’assentiment de ton conjoint que tu as acheté les décorations de Noël cette année?

> Les décorations de Noël que tu as achetées ont été choisies de concert avec ton conjoint?

> C’est d’un commun accord avec ton conjoint que tu as acheté les décorations de Noël cette année?

> C’est avec l’accord de ton conjoint que tu as acheté les décorations de Noël cette année?

Je veux savoir comment vous exprimeriez cette idée à l’oral.

Comment: Dans quel contexte / registre de langage souhaité ?

Comment: À l’oral, registre familier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Tu t'es [entendu](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/s%E2%80%99entendre)(e) avec ton conjoint/ta douce [moitié](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/moiti%C3%A9) sur les
> décorations de Noël ?

Évoquant un désaccord des années antérieures :

> Cette année, t'es-tu [entendu](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/s%E2%80%99entendre)(e) avec ton conjoint/ta douce [moitié](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/moiti%C3%A9) sur
> les décorations de Noël ?

Answer (score 1):

Ton conjoint est bien d'accord avec les décos que t'as achetées cette année ?

Answer (score 0):

> Robert/Ginette est au courant pour les décos de Noël que t'as achetées ?

Answer (score 0):

- Tu as acheté les décorations après que ton mari / ta femme les ait trouvées à son goût  ?
- Ton mari/ta femme et toi vous êtes mis d’accord sur le choix des décorations de Noël que tu as  achetées cette année ?

Étant donné que le tutoiement est utilisé, le mot « conjoint » (aussi « époux » et « épouse »), qui s'emploie dans des contextes assez formels, aurait des connotations  portant sur la relation entre les deux conjoints et même possiblement leur relation avec le locuteur. Si le locuteur s'entretenait avec le conjoint sur la base d'une certaine distance (prenons par exemple le cas d'un détective qui interroge l'un des conjoints à propos d'un crime, et alors le vouvoiement est de rigueur), il existerait trois possibilités équivalentes (« votre mari (femme)/époux (épouse)/conjoint »).

Les termes « assentiment »,« de concert »,« d'un commun accord » ne semblent pas bien propres à ce contexte. « Assentiment » pourrait convenir. « De concert » et « d'un commun accord » semblent  convenir plutôt pour des ententes qui résultent de discussion rationnelle.

« Avec l'accord » implique qu'une permission plus ou moins formelle a été donnée, ce qui laisse entendre que la relation entre les conjoints est d'un type très particulier, peut-être pas très habituel, l'un des partenaires étant soumis à des interdictions plus ou moins rigides en ce qui concerne des choses pour lesquelles ce type de rapport entres personnes mariées n'existe pas d'ordinaire. Si c'est le cas, alors la cinquième phrase convient.